# Reading xml attributes in PHP

Tags: php, xml

My XML file has the following code:

```
<Object>
  <hasOLE>false</hasOLE> 
  <Attribute Name="Absolute Number">
    <Value>1</Value> 
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="Object Number">
    <Value>1</Value> 
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="Object Heading">
    <Value>Introduction</Value> 
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="Object Text">
    <Value /> 
  </Attribute>
</Object>
```

How can I read the attributes in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: u can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php dom document class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `simplexml_load_string`:

```
$string = '<Object>
    <hasOLE>false</hasOLE> 
    <Attribute Name="Absolute Number">
        <Value>1</Value> 
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Object Number">
        <Value>1</Value> 
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Object Heading">
        <Value>Introduction</Value> 
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Object Text">
        <Value /> 
    </Attribute>
</Object>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $string );
// Or $xml = simplexml_load_file( $filename ); if it's inside a file.
```

And access it as simple like this:

```
echo $xml->Attribute->attributes(); //Absolute Number 
echo $xml->Attribute->Value;        // 1
```